# Word coincidence in a text

Tags: python-2.7

## Hi guys, i'm trying to count  how many times a word and his contractions (like you and you're). The problem is I don't see the way to catch the contraction of my word too.

```
def paraula(file,palabrabuscar):
    abrirLetra = open(file) #Open the file
    palabras = ""
    vegades = 0
    for palabras in abrirLetra.read().split():#I split all words in text
        if (palabras == palabrabuscar) :#Look for coincidence
            vegades = vegades +1
            
    abrirLetra.close()
    return vegades

file = 'lletra.txt'
print paraula(file,"you")
```

Comment: Forgive me if I'm wrong, but won't calling string.split() split it by character?

Answer (score 0):

You may want to split your file at apostrophes, spaces, as well as any other punctuation mark. To split at multiple delimiters, you need to `import re` and use regular expressions.

If you also want to match words with different case (e.g. 'you and 'YOU'), then you will need to use `lower()`.

```
import re  # use regular expressions

def paraula(file,palabrabuscar):
    abrirLetra = open(file) #Open the file
    palabras = ""
    vegades = 0
    for palabras in re.split(r'[\s\'\"\.,;]+', abrirLetra.read()):
        # split at every: \s whitespace
        #                 \' apostrophe
        #                 \" quotation mark
        #                 \. full stop
        #                  , comma
        #                  ; semi-colon
        #
        # The plus sign at the end splits at one or more delimiters in
        # a row (for example "Hello. Hi." has a full stop and a space 
        # together between Hello and Hi).
        #
        # Backslashes are added before special characters
        # (for example s matches the letter s, but \s matches whitespace).

        if (palabras.lower() == palabrabuscar.lower()): #Look for coincidence
            # Convert both to lowercase if you want to match
            # you, You and YOU.
            vegades = vegades +1

    abrirLetra.close()
    return vegades

file = 'lletra.txt'
print paraula(file,"you")
```